# Accessing downloaded files in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I've my Django project deployed on Apache.
The script downloads and saves file(s), every time a user submits an input, in a directory ('/media/data/saved_files/') on the same machine. And I'd like to access these files in one of my templates. How can I do this? Is there any other ways around it?
Eg:

```
{{ STATIC_URL }}"file_name"
```

or

```
'/media/data/saved_files/file_name'
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add MEDIA_URL with TEMPLATES_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS or just write simple template tag like this (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/):

```
import os

from django.template import Library
from django.conf import settings


register = Library()


@register.simple_tag
def media_url(filename):
   return os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_URL, filename)
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
{% load utils_tags %}

{% media_url 'data/saved_files/myfile.png' %}
```

Comment: Hi ssbb, thanks for the quick response. But I still can't get the file path in my template. Eg: it seem to be looking in the 'http://localhost:8000/media/data/saved_files/myfile.txt'. The files actually lives inside the system /media/data/saved_files/ dir.

Comment: If you can't access file by url, try this steps:

Comment: 1. Check MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT setup correctly https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/
2. Put this in you urls.py - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cd7d68dcb473f53768b7